# need to change attribute type from integer to decimal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up all the models in my app with integer values for the attributes, but now I've come to add to the database I've realised that they need to be decimals (to allow up to 2 decimal places).

There are lots of attributes that need changing (i.e. around 20 per model).

My searching tells me that a database migration is needed for each model and something like

```
rails generate migration change_data_type_for_tpn
```

and then edit the migration to say

```
class ChangeDataTypeForTPN < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :tpn do |t|
      t.change :pot, :decimal, :precision => 2, :scale => 1
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :tpn do |t|
      t.change :pot, :integer
    end
  end
end
```

My questions are:

1. Does this look right?
2. Why does it need self.up and self.down i.e. what does that actually mean?
3. If I want to do more than one attribute-type-change at the same time can I just add another t.change line below the first one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it looks right, i will post what i would so though soon.
2. self.up and down is how your migration interacts with your database, when you run a rake db:migrate each migration will run the self.up in your database, and when you use rollback methods like rake db:rollback it will use the self.down method
3. yeah you can update multiple lines.

Here i posted an example of what i would do: https://gist.github.com/kazpsp/6226710

```
class Fixtables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   change_column :table_name, :column_name, :newtype
   change_column :table_name, :column_name2, :newtype
   change_column :table_name2, :column_name, :newtype
  end
  def self.down
   change_column :table_name, :column_name, :oldtype
   change_column :table_name, :column_name2, :oldtype
   change_column :table_name2, :column_name, :oldtype
  end
end
```

Now more in depth thought of the problem this type change can make your database irreversable, think this situation, you have a table that used to have a integer as a column type, and u change it to a string, when you populate that DB, you will have strings in that column for many DB rows, if you try to rollback your DB it would display an error since string values that are now on the rows can become integers when you rollback, so be carefull when you do this type of migrations cause they can be irreversable, unless you loose all your data.

Comment: ah ok, so self-down should have the old data type - will edit my original post

Comment: Thanks - I don't mind it being irreversible.  The database is completely empty anyway.

Comment: I ran the migration (rake db:migrate) but it's still saying 'invalid value' when I try to put in a decimal in local host.  Is there another step I might be missing?

Comment: paste the schema of the table you are looking, its in this route: db>schema.rb

Comment: actually I think the issue is that I called it 'tpn' but it's actually 'tpns'.  Can I just edit the migration and run it again, or do I need to create a whole new migration?

Comment: you can try rake db:rollback, if it succeds you can modify the same migration and run it again, if it dosnt succed create a new one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35394/discussion-between-rodrigo-zurek-and-tessad)

Comment: create_table "tpns", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "aman"
    t.integer  "dex"
    t.integer  "sod"
    t.integer  "pot"
    t.integer  "calc"
    t.integer  "mag"
    t.integer  "phos"
    t.integer  "chlor"
    t.integer  "acet"
    t.integer  "zinc"
    t.integer  "selen"
    t.integer  "iod"
    t.integer  "hep"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end